# Java eclipse - value changes itself at the start of the program

Tags: java, eclipse

Usually I know what the problem is or how to  describe it. But this is just beyond my understanding.

I have a set of `public static` variables in my main class, the first thing that happens in the `main(String[] a)` method of the project is displaying two of those. But for some reason when I changed it in the declaration, the program still runs of the old one. I have attempted removing the `static` and calling them from within the method with the same result. As far as I can test all variables in this section of the program suffer from the same problem.

Here is the screenshot of the code and variable (I made a break point on the main method just to be sure nothing else runs):
[image: Code with unexpected change of variable value]

In case this matters, I have actually changed computers since the last version of the app, I have a new installation of everything but I rebuild all directories as they were and besides this variable change (or lack there of) everything runs with no issues.

Comment: You could try making it `final` to find anywhere that might be changing it...

Comment: Sadly no change. The value is still "...0.0.7" :/

Comment: Have you done a Project > Clean ?

Comment: Yes, few times even... I have also deleted and recreated the start-up configurations, no luck there.

Comment: Are you using reflection anywhere?

Comment: No, unless they are somewhere in LWJGL which I'm using for input and graphical output, later in the code.

Comment: Does the class called `Main` have a constructor without arguments?  If so, you're actually calling it in your static initialisers.  Make sure the constructor doesn't do anything evil.

Comment: As most of the work is done by other objects the constructor is empty, I've solved the problem (read below).

Answer (score 0):

Ok it took a bit of thinking outside of the box but I've fixed it (not all steps may be required, but when tried on their own they didn't work):

- Close all tabs (files) in Eclipse
- Close Eclipse
- Open and save (without editing) the .java file in other program (like Notepad++)
- Open Eclipse
- Right-Click inside Package Explorer and 'Refresh' (or use F5)
- Open the file and build the project

It's a very strange bug and I hope if someone else finds it the 'fix' will work for them.

Comment: Glad to know that the issue is solved.
But just out of curiosity, had you checked the time-stamp of the generated class files to make sure that the changes that you did were actually being reflected?

Comment: The file was updating and when opened in Notepad++ it had the new string. I would assume that Eclipse had a cache of the file and for some reason would not let it go.